# Can I safely redirect all incoming HTTP traffic when new files are being uploaded via FTP?

Tags: web-server, ftp, redirect, http

Our website is receiving an update very soon, we've already updated all the PHP, HTML & CSS files so pretty much we just now need to upload the new files to the web server via FTP. Being that the new website is around 5,000 files it's going to take quite awhile to upload them to the webserver when we make the new update go live. When the files are being uploaded to the web server any visitors will either receive errors or the website won't render properly being that the new files are still being uploaded.

During this period of time (when the new files are being uploaded to the server via FTP) can we redirect all incoming HTTP traffic to a different URL indicating to visitors that "the website is receiving an update and will be back up shortly" without it disrupting the files being uploaded via FTP? I know FTP and HTTP are completely different protocols, but my concern is that if we redirect all incoming HTTP traffic it may interfere with the new files being uploaded via FTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from this being a pretty rudimentary method for managing a website's assets, there's a less disruptive method that still uses the same tooling:

1. Upload the files to a separate directory.
2. When they're all done, recursively move them to the live directory, overwriting the existing files.

This shouldn't take longer than a basic filesystem operation. Even thousands of files will take a scant few seconds to do this, probably not disrupting anyone's access.

But maybe you should start opening a conversation up about a better system for deploys... =)

> [...] my concern is that if we redirect all incoming HTTP traffic it may interfere with the new files being uploaded via FTP?

It will have absolutely zero impact to the FTP operation.